# Output GET request on web page?

Tags: python, rest, http-get

I'm just in the middle of setting up the JAMF Casper Suite, and have been playing around with the API.

I want to know how to output a JSS API call to a webpage. I have worked out how to do the request using cURL, but can't figure out how to do it on the web.

What would be the best method of achieving this? I tried creating a python script but am not sure that's the best method.

I just need to call: https://example.jamfcloud.com/JSSResource/accounts for example using a GET request, with the username:password in the header. Then I could just pipe the output, to show a list of accounts.

What is the best way of achieving this, so anyone visiting something.com/accounts could see an output of accounts?

Here is some code I tried:

```python
import urllib.request
import base64

request = urllib.request.urlopen('https://example.jamfcloud.com/JSSResource/accounts')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(user + ':' + pass))

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: post your code. what do you mean by curl? using curl from cli? from another language?

Comment: From cli I can cURL the api endpoint, and get results, but I can't work out how to run the command and output it to a webpage. So for example, if I call test.com/api.py it will run a command, and output the results to the page

Comment: Are you using `subprocess.check_output` in your python script? And for that matter are you calling curl from your python script or are you using `urllib2` and doing the request through python?

Comment: 'import urllib.request
import base64

request = urllib.request.urlopen('https://example.jamfcloud.com/JSSResource/accounts')
request.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(user + ':' + pass))

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)' that is the code I'm trying to use

Comment: if you're wanting to use a website python is not going to be your best choice. use something that was intended for web use like php.

Comment: @Pamblam what code would I use in PHP to make a get request, with auth in the headers? Something like this: **<?php
$response = http_get("http://www.example.com/", array("timeout"=>1), $info);
print_r($info);
?>**

Comment: here's a curl function for PHP you can just alter it to send the correct headers and then echo the response.. http://blog.geneticcoder.com/2015/02/26/curl-function-for-php/